# quickfixj logs have no newlines for windows notepad

Tags: quickfix, quickfixj

I need to change the charset or add

```
        System.setProperty("line.separator", "\r\n");
```

so I added the above in the main function but that doesn't make newlines appear in the quickfixj log. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use Notepad.

I don't mean that to be a flippant answer, but as a fellow developer I'm sure you know that there are dozens of other text editors out there, and *all of them are better than Notepad*.

This won't be the last time you open a file that uses Unix-style line endings, so you might as well use a full-featured editor that can handle them.

Comment: That's the one that I prefer.

Comment: Notepad++ isn't bad either.